# How do I calculate percent difference between max and min values in consecutive rows by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**Request**

I was able to identify the minimum and maximum in_state_total values by the group. I would like to add another column that calculates the percent difference between the maximum value and the minimum value for each group. The result should occupy both rows for each group so I can further sort the data before plotting. I would prefer a dplyr approach, but am open to exploring other options in order to deepen my understanding of the issue and the potential solutions.

**Current Code**

```
tuition_cost_clean %>% 
  filter(degree_length == "4 Year") %>% 
  arrange(state, desc(in_state_total)) %>%
  group_by(state_abbr) %>% 
  slice(which.max(in_state_total), which.min(in_state_total)) %>% 
  select(name, state_abbr, in_state_total)
```

**Current Output**

```
name                                          state_abbr            in_state_total
<chr>                                         <chr>                 <dbl>
Alaska Pacific University                      AK                   28130       
Alaska Bible College                           AK                   15000       
Spring Hill College                            AL                   52926       
Huntsville Bible College                       AL                   5390        
Hendrix College                                AR                   58074       
University of Arkansas for Medical Sciences    AR                   8197
```

**Desired Output**

```
name                                          state_abbr   in_state_total    pct_change 
<chr>                                         <chr>         <dbl>
Alaska Pacific University                      AK           28130            46.6761%     
Alaska Bible College                           AK           15000            46.6761%
Spring Hill College                            AL           52926            89.816%
Huntsville Bible College                       AL           5390             89.816%
Hendrix College                                AR           58074            85.8852%
University of Arkansas for Medical Sciences    AR           8197             85.8852%
```

**Data**

```
tuition_cost_clean <- structure(list(name = c("Aaniiih Nakoda College", "Abilene Christian University", 
"Abraham Baldwin Agricultural College", "Academy College", "Academy of Art University", 
"Adams State University", "Adelphi University", "Adirondack Community College", 
"Adrian College", "Advanced Technology Institute", "Adventist University of Health Sciences", 
"Agnes Scott College", "Aiken Technical College", "Aims Community College", 
"Alabama Agricultural and Mechanical University", "Alabama Southern Community College", 
"Alabama State University", "Alamance Community College", "Alaska Bible College", 
"Alaska Pacific University", "Albany College of Pharmacy and Health Sciences", 
"Albany State University", "Albany Technical College", "Albertus Magnus College", 
"Albion College", "Albright College", "Alcorn State University", 
"Alderson-Broaddus University", "Alexandria Technical and Community College", 
"Alfred University", "Allan Hancock College", "Allegany College of Maryland", 
"Allegheny College", "Allegheny Wesleyan College", "Allen College", 
"Allen County Community College", "Allen University", "Alliant International University", 
"Alma College", "Alpena Community College", "Alvernia University", 
"Alverno College", "Alvin Community College", "Amarillo College", 
"Amberton University", "American Academy McAllister Institute of Funeral Service", 
"American Academy of Art", "American Academy of Dramatic Arts", 
"American Academy of Dramatic Arts: West", "American Baptist College", 
"American Indian College of the Assemblies of God", "American International College", 
"American Jewish University", "American National University: Charlottesville", 
"American National University: Danville", "American National University: Harrisonburg", 
"American National University: Lynchburg", "American National University: Martinsville", 
"American National University: Salem", "American  University SystemFor-profit", 
"American River College", "American Samoa Community College", 
"American University", "American University of Puerto Rico", 
"Amherst College", "Amridge University", "Ancilla College", "Anderson University", 
"Anderson University", "Andrew College", "Andrews University", 
"Angelina College", "Angelo State University", "Anna Maria College", 
"Anne Arundel Community College", "Anoka Technical College", 
"Anoka-Ramsey Community College", "Antelope Valley College", 
"Antioch College", "Antioch University Los Angeles", "Antioch University Midwest", 
"Antioch University Santa Barbara", "Antioch University Seattle", 
"Apex School of Theology", "Appalachian Bible College", "Appalachian State University", 
"Aquinas College", "Aquinas College", "Arapahoe Community College", 
"Arcadia University", "Arizona Christian University", "Arizona State University", 
"Arizona Western College", "Arkansas Baptist College", "Arkansas Northeastern College", 
"Arkansas State University", "Arkansas State University Mid-South", 
"Arkansas State University: Beebe", "Arkansas State University: Mountain Home", 
"Arkansas State University: Newport", "Arkansas Tech University", 
"Arlington Baptist University", "Armstrong State University", 
"Art Academy of Cincinnati", "Art Center College of Design", 
"Art Institute of Houston", "Art Institute of Philadelphia", 
"Art Institute of Phoenix", "Art Institute of Pittsburgh", "ASA College", 
"Asbury University", "Asheville-Buncombe Technical Community College", 
"Ashford University", "Ashland Community and Technical College", 
"Ashland University", "Ashworth College", "Asnuntuck Community College", 
"Assumption College", "Assumption College for Sisters", "Athens State University", 
"Athens Technical College", "Atlanta Metropolitan State College", 
"Atlanta Technical College", "Atlantic Cape Community College", 
"Atlantic University College", "Auburn University", "Auburn University at Montgomery", 
"Augsburg University", "Augusta Technical College", "Augusta University", 
"Augustana College", "Augustana University", "Aultman College of Nursing and Health Sciences", 
"Aurora University", "Austin College", "Austin Community College", 
"Austin Graduate School of Theology", "Austin Peay State University", 
"Ave Maria University", "Averett University", "Avila University", 
"Azusa Pacific University", "Babson College", "Baker University", 
"Bakersfield College", "Baldwin Wallace University", "Ball State University", 
"Baltimore City Community College", "Baptist Bible College", 
"Baptist College of Florida", "Baptist College of Health Sciences", 
"Baptist Missionary Association Theological Seminary", "Baptist University of the Americas", 
"Barclay College", "Bard College", "Bard College at Simon's Rock", 
"Barnard College", "Barry University", "Barstow Community College", 
"Barton College", "Barton County Community College", "Bastyr University", 
"Bates College", "Bates Technical College", "Baton Rouge Community College", 
"Bay College", "Bay Mills Community College", "Bay Path University", 
"Bay State College", "Bayamon Central University", "Baylor University", 
"Beacon College", "Beaufort County Community College", "Becker College", 
"Beckfield College", "Beis Medrash Heichal Dovid", "Belhaven University", 
"Bellarmine University", "Bellevue College", "Bellevue University", 
"Bellin College", "Bellingham Technical College", "Belmont Abbey College", 
"Belmont College", "Belmont University", "Beloit College", "Bemidji State University", 
"Benedict College", "Benedictine College", "Benedictine University", 
"Benjamin Franklin Institute of Technology", "Bennett College for Women", 
"Bennington College", "Bentley University", "Berea College", 
"Bergen Community College", "Bergin University of Canine Studies", 
"Berkeley City College", "Berklee College of Music", "Berkshire Community College"
), state = c("Montana", "Texas", "Georgia", "Minnesota", "California", 
"Colorado", "New York", "New York", "Michigan", "Virginia", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "South Carolina", "Colorado", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "North Carolina", "Alaska", "Alaska", "New York", 
"Georgia", "Georgia", "Connecticut", "Michigan", "Pennsylvania", 
"Mississippi", "West Virginia", "Minnesota", "New York", "California", 
"Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Ohio", "Iowa", "Kansas", "South Carolina", 
"California", "Michigan", "Michigan", "Pennsylvania", "Wisconsin", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "New York", "Illinois", "New York", 
"California", "Tennessee", "Arizona", "Massachusetts", "California", 
"Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", 
"West Virginia", "California", NA, NA, NA, "Massachusetts", "Alabama", 
"Indiana", "South Carolina", "Indiana", "Georgia", "Michigan", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Massachusetts", "Maryland", "Minnesota", "Minnesota", 
"California", "Ohio", "California", "Ohio", "California", "Washington", 
"North Carolina", "West Virginia", "North Carolina", "Michigan", 
"Tennessee", "Colorado", "Pennsylvania", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", 
"Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Texas", "Georgia", "Ohio", 
"California", "Texas", "Pennsylvania", "Arizona", "Pennsylvania", 
"New York", "Kentucky", "North Carolina", "California", "Kentucky", 
"Ohio", "Georgia", "Connecticut", "Massachusetts", "New Jersey", 
"Alabama", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Georgia", "New Jersey", NA, 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Minnesota", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Illinois", 
"South Dakota", "Ohio", "Illinois", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", 
"Tennessee", "Florida", "Virginia", "Missouri", "California", 
"Massachusetts", "Kansas", "California", "Ohio", "Indiana", "Maryland", 
"Missouri", "Florida", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Texas", "Kansas", 
"New York", "Massachusetts", "New York", "Florida", "California", 
"North Carolina", "Kansas", "Washington", "Maine", "Washington", 
"Louisiana", "Michigan", "Michigan", "Massachusetts", "Massachusetts", 
NA, "Texas", "Florida", "North Carolina", "Massachusetts", "Kentucky", 
"New York", "Mississippi", "Kentucky", "Washington", "Nebraska", 
"Wisconsin", "Washington", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Tennessee", 
"Wisconsin", "Minnesota", "South Carolina", "Kansas", "Illinois", 
"Massachusetts", "North Carolina", "Vermont", "Massachusetts", 
"Kentucky", "New Jersey", "California", "California", "Massachusetts", 
"Massachusetts"), state_code = c("MT", "TX", "GA", "MN", "CA", 
"CO", "NY", "NY", "MI", "VA", "FL", "GA", "SC", "CO", "AL", "AL", 
"AL", "NC", "AK", "AK", "NY", "GA", "GA", "CT", "MI", "PA", "MS", 
"WV", "MN", "NY", "CA", "MD", "PA", "OH", "IA", "KS", "SC", "CA", 
"MI", "MI", "PA", "WI", "TX", "TX", "TX", "NY", "IL", "NY", "CA", 
"TN", "AZ", "MA", "CA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "WV", 
"CA", "AS", "DC", "PR", "MA", "AL", "IN", "SC", "IN", "GA", "MI", 
"TX", "TX", "MA", "MD", "MN", "MN", "CA", "OH", "CA", "OH", "CA", 
"WA", "NC", "WV", "NC", "MI", "TN", "CO", "PA", "AZ", "AZ", "AZ", 
"AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "TX", "GA", "OH", 
"CA", "TX", "PA", "AZ", "PA", "NY", "KY", "NC", "CA", "KY", "OH", 
"GA", "CT", "MA", "NJ", "AL", "GA", "GA", "GA", "NJ", "PR", "AL", 
"AL", "MN", "GA", "GA", "IL", "SD", "OH", "IL", "TX", "TX", "TX", 
"TN", "FL", "VA", "MO", "CA", "MA", "KS", "CA", "OH", "IN", "MD", 
"MO", "FL", "TN", "TX", "TX", "KS", "NY", "MA", "NY", "FL", "CA", 
"NC", "KS", "WA", "ME", "WA", "LA", "MI", "MI", "MA", "MA", "PR", 
"TX", "FL", "NC", "MA", "KY", "NY", "MS", "KY", "WA", "NE", "WI", 
"WA", "NC", "OH", "TN", "WI", "MN", "SC", "KS", "IL", "MA", "NC", 
"VT", "MA", "KY", "NJ", "CA", "CA", "MA", "MA"), type = c("Public", 
"Private", "Public", "For Profit", "For Profit", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Private", "For Profit", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "For Profit", "For Profit", 
"For Profit", "For Profit", "For Profit", "For Profit", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "For Profit", "For Profit", "For Profit", 
"For Profit", "For Profit", "Private", "Public", "For Profit", 
"Public", "Private", "For Profit", "Public", "Private", "Private", 
"Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", 
"Private", "For Profit", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Private", "For Profit", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Private", "Public"), degree_length = c("2 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year"), room_and_board = c(NA, 10350, 8474, NA, 
16648, 8782, 16030, 11660, 11318, NA, 4200, 12330, NA, NA, 8379, 
NA, 5422, NA, 5700, 7300, 10920, 8878, NA, 13200, 12380, 12070, 
9608, 8860, NA, 12516, NA, NA, 12140, 4000, 7282, 5070, 7230, 
NA, 10998, NA, NA, 8546, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17955, 13255, 8640, 
6250, 14300, 17362, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14880, 
NA, 14740, NA, 9600, 9830, 9890, 10636, 9078, 5500, 9130, 14630, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 7640, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7960, 8304, 9332, NA, 
NA, 13800, 10674, 12648, 6700, 8826, NA, 8160, NA, 5280, NA, 
NA, 7870, 6500, 11385, 6700, NA, 9600, NA, 10928, 2758, 9500, 
7160, NA, NA, NA, 9941, NA, NA, 12694, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 13332, 6980, 10280, NA, 9640, 10572, 8248, NA, 11700, 12527, 
NA, NA, 10700, 11436, 9976, 7200, 10076, 16312, 8410, NA, 9554, 
10234, NA, 7500, 4612, 2900, 3150, 2500, 9300, 15488, 14916, 
17225, 11100, NA, 10120, 5794, 7590, 15224, NA, NA, 3200, NA, 
12799, 13300, NA, 12595, 11390, NA, 13800, NA, 4500, 8500, 12250, 
NA, 8730, NA, NA, 10355, NA, 12120, 8830, 8408, 6200, 10300, 
9480, 12400, 8114, 15610, 16320, 6764, NA, NA, NA, 18180, NA), 
    in_state_tuition = c(2380, 34850, 4128, 17661, 27810, 9440, 
    38660, 5375, 37087, 13680, 15150, 41160, 5160, 2281, 9698, 
    4440, 11068, 2310, 9300, 20830, 35105, 6726, 3246, 32060, 
    45775, 45306, 7144, 27910, 5416, 33484, 1418, 4140, 47540, 
    6400, 19970, 3150, 13340, 18000, 40258, 4530, 34885, 28302, 
    1998, 2670, 12840, 17160, 34100, 35160, 35160, 10950, 958, 
    35680, 31826, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 8150, 
    1416, 3700, 48459, 6946, 56426, 6900, 17330, 28000, 30450, 
    17388, 29288, 2625, 8489, 37860, 4110, 5584, 5073, 1420, 
    35718, 20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 6200, 14720, 7214, 32574, 
    23600, 4811, 43580, 26796, 10822, 2520, 8760, 2450, 8608, 
    3274, 3600, 3570, 3480, 9068, 13190, 6384, 33889, 43416, 
    24024, 14850, 21645, 23376, 14065, 30198, 2354, 12160, 5310, 
    21342, 1399, 4404, 40958, 5888, 6810, 3292, 4008, 3350, 5096, 
    4525, 11276, 10288, 38800, 3494, 10758, 42135, 33018, 18510, 
    24260, 39985, 2550, 11900, 8411, 20850, 34400, 19900, 38880, 
    51104, 29830, 1418, 32586, 9896, 2893, 14150, 12300, 14700, 
    6690, 7800, 19690, 54680, 55732, 55032, 29850, 1391, 30880, 
    3440, 26166, 53794, 4783, 3981, 4830, 3250, 34225, 27750, 
    5775, 45727, 39016, 2344, 39200, 4000, 9500, 25300, 42200, 
    4258, 9390, 22178, 2790, 18500, 4973, 34310, 50040, 8696, 
    16600, 29530, 34290, 18690, 18513, 54360, 49880, 39990, 5610, 
    9450, 1432, 42750, 8569), in_state_total = c(2380, 45200, 
    12602, 17661, 44458, 18222, 54690, 17035, 48405, 13680, 19350, 
    53490, 5160, 2281, 18077, 4440, 16490, 2310, 15000, 28130, 
    46025, 15604, 3246, 45260, 58155, 57376, 16752, 36770, 5416, 
    46000, 1418, 4140, 59680, 10400, 27252, 8220, 20570, 18000, 
    51256, 4530, 34885, 36848, 1998, 2670, 12840, 17160, 34100, 
    53115, 48415, 19590, 7208, 49980, 49188, 18735, 18735, 18735, 
    18735, 18735, 18735, 8150, 1416, 3700, 63339, 6946, 71166, 
    6900, 26930, 37830, 40340, 28024, 38366, 8125, 17619, 52490, 
    4110, 5584, 5073, 1420, 43358, 20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 
    6200, 22680, 15518, 41906, 23600, 4811, 57380, 37470, 23470, 
    9220, 17586, 2450, 16768, 3274, 8880, 3570, 3480, 16938, 
    19690, 17769, 40589, 43416, 33624, 14850, 32573, 26134, 23565, 
    37358, 2354, 12160, 5310, 31283, 1399, 4404, 53652, 5888, 
    6810, 3292, 4008, 3350, 5096, 4525, 24608, 17268, 49080, 
    3494, 20398, 52707, 41266, 18510, 35960, 52512, 2550, 11900, 
    19111, 32286, 44376, 27100, 48956, 67416, 38240, 1418, 42140, 
    20130, 2893, 21650, 16912, 17600, 9840, 10300, 28990, 70168, 
    70648, 72257, 40950, 1391, 41000, 9234, 33756, 69018, 4783, 
    3981, 8030, 3250, 47024, 41050, 5775, 58322, 50406, 2344, 
    53000, 4000, 14000, 33800, 54450, 4258, 18120, 22178, 2790, 
    28855, 4973, 46430, 58870, 17104, 22800, 39830, 43770, 31090, 
    26627, 69970, 66200, 46754, 5610, 9450, 1432, 60930, 8569
    ), out_of_state_tuition = c(2380, 34850, 12550, 17661, 27810, 
    20456, 38660, 9935, 37087, 13680, 15150, 41160, 8010, 13018, 
    17918, 8880, 19396, 8070, 9300, 20830, 35105, 19802, 5916, 
    32060, 45775, 45306, 7144, 27910, 5416, 33484, 7898, 9210, 
    47540, 6400, 19970, 3150, 13340, 18000, 40258, 6840, 34885, 
    28302, 4818, 5880, 12840, 17160, 34100, 35160, 35160, 10950, 
    958, 35680, 31826, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 
    8150, 9546, 3700, 48459, 6946, 56426, 6900, 17330, 28000, 
    30450, 17388, 29288, 5535, 20939, 37860, 12180, 5584, 5073, 
    9760, 35718, 20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 6200, 14720, 22021, 
    32574, 23600, 18671, 43580, 26796, 28336, 9510, 8760, 4250, 
    15298, 5014, 5760, 5580, 5310, 15848, 13190, 19866, 33889, 
    43416, 24024, 14850, 21645, 23376, 14065, 30198, 8114, 12160, 
    18000, 21342, 1399, 13170, 40958, 5888, 12870, 5962, 12088, 
    6020, 8096, 4525, 30524, 22048, 38800, 6164, 29796, 42135, 
    33018, 18510, 24260, 39985, 13020, 11900, 24467, 20850, 34400, 
    19900, 38880, 51104, 29830, 7838, 32586, 26468, 6973, 14150, 
    12300, 14700, 6690, 7800, 19690, 54680, 55732, 55032, 29850, 
    9131, 30880, 3440, 26166, 53794, 10214, 8059, 8910, 3250, 
    34225, 27750, 5775, 45727, 39016, 8104, 39200, 4000, 9500, 
    25300, 42200, 9689, 9390, 22178, 3460, 18500, 8070, 34310, 
    50040, 8696, 16600, 29530, 34290, 18690, 18513, 54360, 49880, 
    39990, 10650, 9450, 9622, 42750, 15589), out_of_state_total = c(2380, 
    45200, 21024, 17661, 44458, 29238, 54690, 21595, 48405, 13680, 
    19350, 53490, 8010, 13018, 26297, 8880, 24818, 8070, 15000, 
    28130, 46025, 28680, 5916, 45260, 58155, 57376, 16752, 36770, 
    5416, 46000, 7898, 9210, 59680, 10400, 27252, 8220, 20570, 
    18000, 51256, 6840, 34885, 36848, 4818, 5880, 12840, 17160, 
    34100, 53115, 48415, 19590, 7208, 49980, 49188, 18735, 18735, 
    18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 8150, 9546, 3700, 63339, 6946, 
    71166, 6900, 26930, 37830, 40340, 28024, 38366, 11035, 30069, 
    52490, 12180, 5584, 5073, 9760, 43358, 20670, 16210, 22575, 
    27435, 6200, 22680, 30325, 41906, 23600, 18671, 57380, 37470, 
    40984, 16210, 17586, 4250, 23458, 5014, 11040, 5580, 5310, 
    23718, 19690, 31251, 40589, 43416, 33624, 14850, 32573, 26134, 
    23565, 37358, 8114, 12160, 18000, 31283, 1399, 13170, 53652, 
    5888, 12870, 5962, 12088, 6020, 8096, 4525, 43856, 29028, 
    49080, 6164, 39436, 52707, 41266, 18510, 35960, 52512, 13020, 
    11900, 35167, 32286, 44376, 27100, 48956, 67416, 38240, 7838, 
    42140, 36702, 6973, 21650, 16912, 17600, 9840, 10300, 28990, 
    70168, 70648, 72257, 40950, 9131, 41000, 9234, 33756, 69018, 
    10214, 8059, 12110, 3250, 47024, 41050, 5775, 58322, 50406, 
    8104, 53000, 4000, 14000, 33800, 54450, 9689, 18120, 22178, 
    3460, 28855, 8070, 46430, 58870, 17104, 22800, 39830, 43770, 
    31090, 26627, 69970, 66200, 46754, 10650, 9450, 9622, 60930, 
    15589)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: add `mutate(pct_change = abs(diff(in_state_total))/max(in_state_total)*100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff`/`lag` to calculate difference :

```
library(dplyr)

tuition_cost_clean %>% 
  filter(degree_length == "4 Year") %>% 
  arrange(state, desc(in_state_total)) %>%
  group_by(state_code) %>% 
  slice(which.max(in_state_total), which.min(in_state_total)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = -diff(in_state_total)/max(in_state_total) * 100) %>%
  select(name, state_code, in_state_total, pct_change) 


#   name                                             state_code in_state_total pct_change
#   <chr>                                            <chr>               <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Alaska Pacific University                        AK                  28130      46.7 
# 2 Alaska Bible College                             AK                  15000      46.7 
# 3 Auburn University                                AL                  24608      72.3 
# 4 Athens State University                          AL                   6810      72.3 
# 5 Arkansas Baptist College                         AR                  17586       4.65
# 6 Arkansas State University                        AR                  16768       4.65
# 7 Arizona Christian University                     AZ                  37470      80.8 
# 8 American Indian College of the Assemblies of God AZ                   7208      80.8 
# 9 American Jewish University                       CA                  49188      80.8 
#10 Bergin University of Canine Studies              CA                   9450      80.8 
# … with 62 more rows
```

Comment: Excellent. If you don't mind, how can I arrange the pct_change in descending order and then select say only the top 20 rows which would come out to the top 10 groups?

Comment: I tried top_n(n = 20, wt = pct_change) with no success.

Comment: If you want to select top 20 rows based on `pct_change`, you can use `top_n` i.e add `ungroup %>% top_n(20, pct_change)` to the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and all you do for the R community.